# Vertex: extract in world relative

Tags: vertices

I have two blender files:

- A table having an armature as parent ([table.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7DcxH-qq_HTcFB0RGVxSEgtUGc/view?usp=sharing))
- A bottle having an armature as parent ([bottle.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7DcxH-qq_HTOWpTMl8zT3E5ZEU/view?usp=sharing))

I export both models in MD5 (http://www.katsbits.com/smforum/index.php?topic=167.0) and I have a different behavior:

The vertices of the table are extracted in world coordinate. But when I extract the vertices of the bottle, the vertices are extracted relative to armature position.

I don't find difference in my Blend files. Where I can configure that ?